# Limiting HTML inputs to specific character types

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, attributes

I have an input that I want to limit the input to only letters (A-Z or a-z).
Only using the attributes in an HTML input element, is it possible to limit the actual input?

Here are some more details:

```
<!-- Code snippet I have now -->
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]">
```

With the `pattern` attribute, this will only let the user know if they haven't met the pattern criteria, right? It won't actually stop them from typing a 5?
With only HTML is it possible to stop a user from entering in numbers (or more specifically only allow them to type in a-z)?

If it isn't possible, how would you do it with JavaScript? I saw somewhere where they had an `onkeypress="someFunction()"` and they checked to see if the input character was a number, and if it was then they would stop it somehow... is that the best way to do this kind of thing?
**HTML**:

```
<!-- Something like that? -->
<input type="text" onkeypress="someFunction()">
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function someFunction() {
    if (event.key < "A" || event.key > "z") {
        // what would I do here?
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function onlyAlphabet(inputVal) {
  var patt=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (patt.test(inputVal)) {
    document.getElementById('text').value = inputVal;
  } else {
    var txt = inputVal.slice(0, -1);
    document.getElementById('text').value = txt;
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" oninput="onlyAlphabet(value)">
```

Comment: What exactly is the `oninput` attribute? Is it like `onchange` except it is called the instant the user changes the input? Unlike `onchange` that only is called once the user changes and un-focuses from the input element

Comment: @JacobHornbeck This event is similar to the onchange event. The difference is that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed

Comment: Okay, thank you! Thank makes sense... I think this is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex instead to check if the criteria is met but yes, I think that may be the best way to do it in plan JS. I'm not aware of a way to do it only with HTML, I don't think it's possible.

```
function someFunction(event) {
  // We check the last character inserted
  if (/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test(event.target.value.slice(event.target.value.length - 1))) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Remove the character from the input
    // Maybe add some class to the element to show error
  }
}
```

Also note that as agata604 sais in his post `keypress` is deprecated and it's better to use `keydown` event.

Comment: The `$` in front of the `event` parameter doesn't mean jQuery does it? I don't want to include jQuery if I don't have to...

Comment: It doesn't, it's just a convention I'm used to. I'll remove it for clarity. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it useing keydown event (keypress is deprecated).

```
function inputPattern(e) {
  var test = e.key.search(/[a-zA-Z]/);
  if(test < 0) e.preventDefault();
}
```

```
<input type="text" onkeydown='inputPattern(event)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about checking if a key is pushed but if it is just an input then you could just do this?

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" onkeypress="someFunction()">
```